# Sync files and folders in windows with commands

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, synchronization, compression, directory

I am a Linux user. I am looking for a command line tool for Widows(2008 R2) for files & folders synchronization. I am looking for a tool like `rsync` in Linux. I have to synchronize between `two Windows machine` and also between `a windows and a Linux(Ubuntu)`.

What everybody use in their company for synchronization when it is to be scheduled to run a script?. Anybody suggest any command line(for scripts) tool for files & folders synchronization(incremental backup sync for VMs and zipped files) in windows platform and also for cross platform synchronization?.

Thank you!

Comment: I heard `rsync` can be installed on windows, but I only know how to use rsync and don't no how to install it on windows!.

Answer (score 2):

Cygwin is:

A collection of tools which provide a Linux look and feel environment for Windows. 
http://www.cygwin.com/

So can you install it and try it out,

Thanx

Comment: In my test I found `rsync` cannot sync virtual machines.

Comment: Just make sure that your ip for the virtual machine is 10.0.0.0 which is NAT ed, Add a new adaptor and set it as bridged, and try using rsync.Virtual box provides an option to add bridge adaptor.

Comment: @ZVIK : cygwin doesn't support itanium.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Deltacopy](http://www.aboutmyip.com/AboutMyXApp/DeltaCopy.jsp) to regulary sync a +14GB PST file over lan.
Is an rsync implementation - changes/adds only the modified bits - so is a lot faster than copying. Supports stopping and resuming.
Creates a windows service on the server side, the client is a command-line utility. Is easy to set up and works well for me.

Comment: Waow, deltacopy seems much better than robocopy !

Answer (score 0):

[Robocopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robocopy) will do what you are asking for Windows sync built into the later versions of Windows and can be installed on older versions.  To do cross platform you can mount NFS, CIFS, etc to get Linux files from Windows.

Comment: I just know Robocopy has Mirroring option(/MIR), One small doubt, does it replicate only changes of a huge file instead replacing complete file?. Because if a file is of huge size(VM) and if it replaces, it takes long time as much as full backup. Thanks!

Comment: @user53864  Full files only.  You want to sync only changes, look into DFS (technically DFS-R these days).

Answer (score 0):

We use [DFS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distributed_File_System_%28Microsoft%29) to keep directories in sync.  No reason it wouldn't work cross-platform if you included a SAMBA share.  And it only replicates changes to files, not whole files.  So if you change the permissions on a large archive, you replicate a few bytes, rather than the whole file.  Take a look at it.

Comment: No good tutorial I found on the internet regarding DFS. If you find any let me know please, especially in using with command line.